# present perfect and past simple in the same sentence

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, since

I have the sentence below from a dialogue between a doctor and a patient. The doctor speaks to the patient in order to reassure him:
"You left the hospital yesterday and only two weeks have passed since the accident"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Those are two independent clauses, so there is no difficulty in having two different time perspectives. I think if the clauses were reversed, as in

> Only two weeks have passed since the accident, and/yet you left the hospital yesterday.

that would be a more logical expression, but there's nothing wrong with the sentence as you posted it.

Comment: Thank you Jack, your reply was very useful.